# In Julia is Int64 slower than Int32?

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. Just a quick question, in Julia, will using type Int64 slow down the calculation comparing with using Int32?
Like,

```
i=1::Int64
j=1::Int64
```

and I want to calculate

```
i+j
```

If I define i and j as Int32, will that making i+j faster than if i and j are Int64?
Thanks!

I know in Fortran, int 8 will be much slower than int 4. Not sure if it is the same in Julia

Comment: "I know in Fortran, int 8 will be much slower than int 4." - Could you provide a citation for that assertion?  I would be surprised if it was true for modern Fortran compilers and modern hardware.  At the very least it is going to depend on the context in which the `i + j` computation appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time will depend on the size of the object.

Consider the following function that does some multiplication, addition and comparison of integers:

```
min200(T) = minimum(x*x+x for x in UnitRange{T}(1:200))
```

Here are the times `using BenchmarkTools`:

```
julia> @btime min200(Int16);
  9.409 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime min200(Int32);
  14.329 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime min200(Int64);
  47.267 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime min200(Int128);
  256.160 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Note that this difference goes down to the assembly code. Let us see how an addition of two integer number gets compiled.

```
julia> @code_native +(Int32(5), Int32(7))
        .text
; ┌ @ int.jl:87 within `+`
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        leal    (%rcx,%rdx), %eax
        popq    %rbp
        retq
        nopl    (%rax)
; └

julia> @code_native +(5,7)
        .text
; ┌ @ int.jl:87 within `+`
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        leaq    (%rcx,%rdx), %rax
        popq    %rbp
        retq
        nopw    (%rax,%rax)
; └
```

You can see that the 32-bit addition used 32-bit registry `%eax` vs 64-bit `%rax` in the second code.

Moreover, when you using features such as `@simd` or GPU computing via `CuArrays` those differences might turn out to be even more significant.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, all of this is architecture dependent. I will be assuming relatively modern 64 bit x86 CPUs for this answer.
For scalar calculations, `Int64` and `Int32` will be the same speed. (`Int16`/`Int8` are roughly the same, though are occasionally slightly slower). For vectorized computation, i.e. `rand(Int64,100) .+ rand(Int64,100)`, `Int64` will be about 2x slower than `Int32`, due to better cache usage, and higher vectorization widths (for AVX-2/AVX-512 etc).